# Emitter follower: \$V_\text{out}\$ smaller than \$V_\text{in}\$

Tags: circuit-design, emitter-follower

Specs: Signal 1 kHz sine, amplitude 100 mV, V<sub>B</sub> = 1.7 V

If we were to connect a sufficiently large resistor to a signal generator, we would expect to measure the voltage over the large resistor to be the voltage amplitude of the signal.

However, if we add a transistor and make an emitter follower using that same large resistor (or even larger), the total voltage drop over the resistor would now be smaller than the voltage amplitude of the signal.

In order to measure the voltage drop I connected my signal generator to an oscilloscope, then I also connected the output of my circuit to my oscilloscope.

The output of my circuit signal pk-pk (top of peak to bottom of trough) value only approached 80 mV. Is there a reason for this to change?

[image]

Comment: "amplitude 100mV, V_B=1.7". What does that mean? 100mV AC superimposed on 1.7V DC?

Comment: Apologies for lack of clarity, I am very new to circuitry.  What I am really trying to know is why the voltage drop across a the resistor is what it is. On the oscilloscope my signal generator had an amplitude of 50mV, if I connected a large resistor to this alone I would expect to measure 50mV voltage drop. However, if I add a transistor in (as shown in the emitter follower) then I measure the amplitude of the output signal for the same large resistor I only get 40mV. What is the transistor doing to change the total signal?

Comment: The base-emitter junction drops ~0.6V. So you need at least that voltage to get meaningfull output.

Comment: Put this circuit into the question using the built-in CircuitLab, set up the signal source and a transient analysis, and see what happens. Equivalently, do the same thing on a breadboard.

Comment: Try increasing the base bias above 1.7 V. It should increase the gain to be nearer to 1 than what you are seeing.

Comment: David, as others have suggested, if the BJT is kept *out of saturation* then you should see a peak-to-peak signal magnitude at the emitter that is just slightly less than the peak-to-peak signal magnitude at the base. However, you must ensure that the emitter always stays at least a volt (preferably two or three volts) below the collector throughout the entire cycle. If the emitter resistor is large enough, it will instead force the emitter voltage to smash up close to the collector voltage and in that case all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

As the input signal changes, causing the output to change, the current in the emitter of the transistor changes. This causes VBE to change which has the effect of decreasing the output amplitude.

You can estimate this by knowing that the effective output impedance of the NPN is 26mV/DC_current. With 1.7 V on, the output is 1.0 V, so 1 mA in the 1 kΩ, giving an impedance of 26 Ω. Thus you should find that the output is 100mV*1k/(1k+26) = 97.5 mV.

Comment: Could my outputs of 80mV differing from the 97.5mV you suggest just be because I have bad equipment?

Comment: Recheck your input amplitude. Also, your input varies from 1.6 to 1.8 V. Apply a DC voltage of each and check the output (if you have a multimeter); it should be approx 0.9 and 1.1, with a swing of 195 mV. Your collector supply should be a few V

Comment: David - the gain formula for the emitter follower indicates that we have always Vout<Vin. Here is the gain: Av=gm*Re/(1+gm*Re) with gm=transconductance.

Comment: where Re is the external resistor, and the dynamic resistance of the be junction = 26mv/IE.    [[edited - RM]]

Comment: Oh no - Re is the external emitter resistor. You must not confuse Re with the dynamic resitsance re=1/gm

Comment: Correct . I can't change my comment.

Comment: @jp314 Ican :-). I have. Suggest better if wanted. An alternative in such cases is to post a new comment, refer to the old one if needed to make time sense of the comments and delete the old one. If the thread in comments is useful enough (which it'snot meant to be :-) ) you could flag a moderator and ask for the change.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate an expression for the gain (dVout/dVin).

[image: Maths derivation]

Where Re is the emitter resistance and re is the transistor's intrinsic emitter resistance, 25mV/Ie at room temperature (or 1/gm as some might like to call it!).